# Making action bar items visible and invisible dynamically

Tags: android

I am developing a messaging application where in I have used list view for messages. In the action bar I have given Clear Conversation option to clear all the messages. I want this Clear Conversation icon to be visible only when messages are present in list view. If there are no messages(ie., when list view is empty) the icon must be invisible. I tried doing this using onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu). But this function gets called only when the activity is called again but I want this to happen without recalling the same activity. As and when I send or receive messages the icon should become visible. When I clear all the messages the icon should become invisible. I'm not able to achieve this, Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the reference to your menu:

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Then wherever, you can do:

menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id).setVisible(false);

Comment: I called  invalidateOptionsMenu(); and it worked out.